# Inequality of variabels for the same product

Tags: gams-math

I have a problem with my model in GAMS. I have two variables `i`and `k` for the same class of products, so that they are alias. In my model is a restriction for which `i`and `k` have to be unequal. I'm not sure how to write this...
The code of the restriction looks as follow:

```
NB6(i,k,t)..
ST(k,t) =g= ET(i,t) - (1-GAM(i,k,t))
;
```

`t`describes a time variable. Can you help me to set the parameters `i`and `k`in that way, that they are unequal? Or do you need some more code?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NB6(i,k,t)$(not sameAs(i,k))..
ST(k,t) =g= ET(i,t) - (1-GAM(i,k,t))
;
```

More info about this topic can be found [here](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_CondExpr.html#UG_CondExpr_SetFunctions_Table).